# Не выполняется условное выражение в route flask

Tags: python, flask

Дорабатываю messendger от SkillBox

Print добавил для отладки

users = {
'Jack' : '123456',
        }

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    """
    requests: {"username": "str","password":"str"}
    response: {"ok": true}
    """
    # Если такой пользователь существует -> зарегистрируем его
    # иначе откажем в доступе
    data = request.json
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']

    if username in users:
        print('проверка')
        real_password = users[username]
        if real_password != password:
            print('проверка')
            return {'ok': False}
            print('Отказано в доступе')
        else:
            users.setdefault(username, password)
            print('Добавляю пользователя в базу')
    print(users)
    return {'ok': True}
```

Клиентская часть:

```
def Login(self):

    self.textBrowser_2.clear()
    self.textBrowser_2.repaint()

    username = self.lineEdit_1.text()
    password = self.lineEdit_2.text()

    if not username:
        self.AuthText('ERROR: username is empty')
        return
    if not password:
        self.AuthText('ERROR: password is empty')
        return

    response = requests.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/login',
        json={"username": username, "password": password}
    )
    if not response.json()['ok']:
        self.AuthText("ERROR: Access denied")
        return

    self.lineEdit_2.clear()
    self.lineEdit_2.repaint()
```

Консоль сервера:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2020 10:47:29] "?[37mGET /history?after=1583999242.2851753 HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
username password
запрос пришёл
{'Jack': '123456'}
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2020 10:47:29] "?[37mPOST /login HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
```

Не выполняются условные выражения, пробовал вызывать проверку как функцию, но она тоже не выполнялась

Comment: check - это функция внутри функции или у вас табуляция съехала?

Comment: и вы что-то делаете с users, который явно нигде не фигурирует, если это глобальная переменная, то лучше это указать через globals

Comment: check - функция внутри функции.
пробовал код напрямую без функции использовать - 0 эффекта. users - глобальный словарь